# I want to populate an array2 with values from 1 to 100, but leaving values which are present in array1

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I want to populate an array2 with values from 1 to 100, but leaving values which are contained in array1. Array1 may not be sorted.

For Example:If array1[2,8,3], I want array2 to be [1,4,5,6,7,9,10,11......98,99,100]

Comment: I want to populate array2 with all the numbers from 1 to 100 but leaving only those numbers which are present in array2. For example: if Array 1 is [2,8,3] then array2 will be [1,4,5,6,7,9,10......100]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you're trying to achieve, this code snippet will solve the problem:

```
for (NSInteger i = 1; i < 101; i++) {
        if (![array1 containsObject:@(i)]) {
            [array2 addObject:@(i)];
        }
    }
```

It'll basically iterate from 1 to 100 and see if current number is contained in array1 — if not, it'll add this number to array2 as a NSNumber instance (if you need strings as in your original code, use `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i]`).

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thanks. I will edit the question, so people can search it easily. Thanks